# WSASocket programming, how to hold on the non-blocking connect() function till some time point?

Tags: sockets

I have a problem in the WSASocket programming. I want to do some trick at server side so that 
it could hold the client side wait for a while in the WSAWaitForEvents() function waiting for 
FD_CONNECT event.

Details are as follows:

1. At the client side, the socket is non-blocking mode. And it tries to connect to the server. It main code is something like:

   ```
   SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

   WSAEvent hEvent = WSACreateEvent();

   WSAEventSelect(s, hEvent, FD_CONNECT); //this also make socket non-blocking mode.

   connect(s, &someserveraddr, sizeof(someserveraddr)); //connect to some server in non-block mode

   WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(1, &hEvent, TRUE, WSA_INFINITE, FALSE); //this will block until success or faile
   ```
2. At the server side, one the server sees a connection from that client, it will do something special which will also take sometime, for example: calling doSomethingLengthy(), So I want to hold the client side blocking at function WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(...) until the server finishes that task. But I don't know how to achieve this. Usually, the server code would like:

   ```
   SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); 

   bind(s, &someaddress, sizeof(someaddress));

   listen(s, 5);

   SOCKET acceptSocket = accept(s, &someotheraddress, sizeof(someotheraddress));
   ```

The problem is that, I don't know where/when to call doSomethingLengthy(). I know that once listen() is done, the client will be notified done and WSAWaitForMultipleEvents() will return. But I cannot call doSomethingLengthy() before listen() otherwise the client side connect() will fail.

Comment: What is `doSomethingLengthy()` really doing, and does it really need to be called per client?  Can you call it beforehand, or even in a parallel thread, and cache the results for use when needed? It is really hard to answer your question without knowing what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: And why would you want to waste a thread's time at the server just to delay a client, whatever your reason for delaying a client?

Comment: this logic is used in a socket-relay implementation. Once the server sees a connection from the client, the server will also need to establish another connection to another server, which will take some time because we are using block mode in the second second. So we want to server to hold the first connection until the second background connection is finished(either fail or success).

Comment: Well you can't. All you can do is reset the inbound connection if the outbound connection fails, unless you can tell the client something via the proxy protocol, if there is one. In any case you don't need `doSomethingLengthy():` the outbound blocking connect will do all the blocking you need.

Comment: OK. On the other hand, what will cause a connect() function succeed after being blocked for a while? I mean, the connection either succeed instantly (in the case of server is listening) or timeout (in the case of on server isn't listening or firewall blocked or whatever, which will be treated as failure). But under what scenarios the connect() will return OK after being blocked for a while? because the distance is too long between server and client?

Comment: It's not likely to happen at all unless there is major packet loss. You're also incorrect to say that failure needs a timeout. ECONNREFUSED is delivered almost instantaneously. ECONNTIMEOUT, which does need a timeout, is much less likely to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The server end of connect happens before the server gets to see the accepted socket, via the backlog queue.

Comment: what if the server doesn't need to see the accepted socket, instead, it will call doSomethingLengthy() for all the accepted sockets? is it possible?

Comment: The point is that the OS establishes the connection in the background and puts it in a queue for `accept()` to pull from.  Even if you do not call `accept()`, `connect()` may still succeed.

Answer (score 0):

`FD_CONNECT` tells you when the socket has connected, but `FD_WRITE` tells you when you are allowed to send data over the connection. So try waiting for `FD_WRITE` instead (do note that you can get `FD_WRITE` multiple times during a connection's lifetime, but you will always get it after a successful `connect()` in addition to `FD_CONNECT`).

Comment: I don't see how this will help. `FD_CONNECT` and the first `FD_WRITE` should be delivered at the same time. They're not really different events: they both mean that the socket send buffer has appeared in response to the connection completion.

Comment: I tested it, and sure enough both events occur without `accept()` being called. I would have expected the socket to not be writable until it has been fully accepted by the server. Oh well.

Comment: How would it know? TCP doesn't tell it about that condition.

Comment: I would have expected the OS to delay the 3-way handshake, for starters.

Comment: Even if it did, which it doesn't, there is still no TCP protocol exchange that tells it that the server's accept() has returned, as opposed to the connect handshake completing, i.e. no way to distinguish FD_CONNECT from FD_WRITE.